How can I snap vertices with different Z values to a plane underneath?

I want to snap the vertices I selected to the plane underneath them. But as you can see, the vertices have different Z positions; and when I select them altogether and try to snap them to the faces below, some of them go through the plane and can be seen from underneath. How can I fix it?

*I will address this object above the plane as a pancake.
1) Keep the pancake and the plane as two separate meshes.
**If it's one mesh - then separate plane from pancake (=instructions=)
2) While being in Edit Mode of the pancake: make sure that selected ONLY vertices which should be snapped.
3) Add new vertex group, name it "Snap" (or some other name) and press Assign to assign selected vertices to vertex-group "Snap"

4) Now go to Object Mode and add to the pancake a Shrinkwrap modifier (from Deform section)
5) Set plane as a Target
6) Click Vertex Group and select vertex group named "Snap" (or other name if you've named it differently)

7) Adjust Offset and Wrap Method (if needed)
That's it :)
